# Displaying the largest and smallest of 4 integers while also displaying their positions

Tags: c

This is my first year taking a Comp-Sci class in college and I've had no programming experience prior to this class. I'm currently trying to write a C program for a class assignment which takes in 4 integer inputs and then displays the largest and smallest of the 4, while also stating the position in which the largest and smallest integers were inputted.

**NOTE**: I'm not allowed to use any functions, arrays, or loops (except the while loop that I'm given below, but no more).

My professor has provided an outline to help get started.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x1, x2, x3, x4;
    int xlarge, xsmall, ixlarge, ixsmall;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("enter x1, x2, x3, x4:\n");
        scanf("%d%d%d%d", &x1, &x2, &x3, &x4);

        /*     add code to calculate xlarge, xsmall,
         *     ixlarge, ixsmall
         * --> between here */

        if ((x1 > x2) && (x1 > x3) && (x1 > x4))
            x1 = xlarge;
        else if ((x2 > x1) && (x2 > x3) && (x2 > x4))
            x2 = xlarge;
        else if ((x3 > x1) && (x3 > x2) && (x3 > x4))
            x3 = xlarge;
        else if ((x4 > x1) && (x4 > x2) && (x4 > x3))
            x4 = xlarge;

        if ((x1 < x2) && (x1 < x3) && (x1 < x4))
            x1 = xsmall;
        else if ((x2 < x1) && (x2 < x3) && (x2 < x4))
            x2 = xsmall;
        else if ((x3 < x1) && (x3 < x2) && (x3 < x4))
            x3 = xsmall;
        else if ((x4 < x1) && (x4 < x2) && (x4 < x3))
            x4 = xsmall;

        if (xlarge = x1)
            ixlarge = 1;
        else if (xlarge = x2)
            ixlarge = 2;
        else if (xlarge = x3)
            ixlarge = 3;
        else if (xlarge = x4)
            ixlarge = 4;

        if (xsmall = x1)
            ixsmall = 1;
        else if (xsmall = x2)
            ixsmall = 2;
        else if (xsmall = x3)
            ixsmall = 3;
        else if (xsmall = x4)
            ixsmall = 4;

        /* <-- and here */

        printf("largest = %4d at position %d, ", xlarge, ixlarge);
        printf("smallest = %4d at position %d\n", xsmall, ixsmall);
    }

    while (1) getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

From what I understand this program should be assigning `xlarge` and `xsmall` to an input if it fulfills the conditions, same for `ixlarge` and `ixsmall`. However, a problem I've run into when trying to run the program is that `xlarge` and `xsmall` are apparently uninitialized, and I'm not sure where to proceed from there.

Comment: Note that you’re using assignment `=` when you want comparison `==`. You’re also assigning `xlarge` into `x1` when you want to do it the other way. Turn your compiler’s warnings to the max and use a debugger to go through your code line by line to see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code:

it should be `xlarge = x1` instead of `x1 = xlarge` and similarly `xsmall = x1` because  it is xlarge that stores value of x1 and not the other way round.

You can also club your if-else like this:

```
if ((x1 > x2) && (x1 > x3) && (x1 > x4))
{
xlarge = x1;
ixlarge = 1;
}
else if ((x2 > x1) && (x2 > x3) && (x2 > x4))
{
xlarge = x2;
ixlarge = 2;
}
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

When you think your problem is too hard

split your problem to small blocks or simplify your question

1.get what i key in(1 integer) and show it

2.get what i key in(2 integers) and show it

3.compare my key in(2 integers) which is bigger and smaller and show it

4.get what i key in(3 integers) and show it,compare my key in(3 integers) which is bigger and smaller and show it

5.try 4 integers

its not about programming ,its about learning method i want to tell you.

### 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main() {
    int FirstKeyIn;
    scanf("%d",&FirstKeyIn);
    printf("I key in :%d \n",FirstKeyIn);



    return 0;
}
```

### 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main() {
    int FirstKeyIn,SecondKeyIn;
    scanf("%d %d",&FirstKeyIn,&SecondKeyIn);
    printf("First  key in :%d \n",FirstKeyIn);
    printf("Second key in :%d \n",SecondKeyIn);


    return 0;
}
```

### 3.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main() {
    int FirstKeyIn,SecondKeyIn;
    int Bigger,Smaller;
    scanf("%d %d",&FirstKeyIn,&SecondKeyIn);
    printf("First  key in :%d \n",FirstKeyIn);
    printf("Second key in :%d \n",SecondKeyIn);
    if(FirstKeyIn>SecondKeyIn){
        Bigger=FirstKeyIn;//save FirstKeyIn value into Bigger
        Smaller=SecondKeyIn;//save SecondKeyIn value into Smaller
    }else{
        Bigger=SecondKeyIn;//save SecondKeyIn value into Bigger
        Smaller=FirstKeyIn;//save FirstKeyIn value into Smaller
    }
    printf("Bigger value is :%d \n",Bigger);
    printf("Smaller value is :%d \n",Smaller);
    return 0;
}
```

### 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main() {
    int FirstKeyIn,SecondKeyIn,ThirdKeyIn;
    int Bigger,Smaller;
    scanf("%d %d %d",&FirstKeyIn,&SecondKeyIn,&ThirdKeyIn);
    printf("First  key in :%d \n",FirstKeyIn);
    printf("Second key in :%d \n",SecondKeyIn);
    printf("Third key in :%d \n",ThirdKeyIn);
    if(FirstKeyIn>SecondKeyIn){
        Bigger=FirstKeyIn;//save FirstKeyIn value into Bigger
        Smaller=SecondKeyIn;//save SecondKeyIn value into Smaller
    }else{
        Bigger=SecondKeyIn;//save SecondKeyIn value into Bigger
        Smaller=FirstKeyIn;//save FirstKeyIn value into Smaller
    }

    if(ThirdKeyIn>Bigger){
        Bigger=ThirdKeyIn;//save ThirdKeyIn value into Bigger
    }
    if(ThirdKeyIn<Smaller){
        Smaller=ThirdKeyIn;//save ThirdKeyIn value into Smaller
    }


    printf("Bigger value is :%d \n",Bigger);
    printf("Smaller value is :%d \n",Smaller);
    return 0;
}
```

---

with max,min place

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main() {
    int FirstKeyIn,SecondKeyIn,ThirdKeyIn;
    int Bigger,Smaller;
    int MaxPlace,MinPlace;
    scanf("%d %d %d",&FirstKeyIn,&SecondKeyIn,&ThirdKeyIn);
    printf("First  key in :%d \n",FirstKeyIn);
    printf("Second key in :%d \n",SecondKeyIn);
    printf("Third key in :%d \n",ThirdKeyIn);
    if(FirstKeyIn>SecondKeyIn){
        Bigger=FirstKeyIn;//save FirstKeyIn value into Bigger
        Smaller=SecondKeyIn;//save SecondKeyIn value into Smaller
        MaxPlace=1;
        MinPlace=2;
    }else{
        Bigger=SecondKeyIn;//save SecondKeyIn value into Bigger
        Smaller=FirstKeyIn;//save FirstKeyIn value into Smaller
        MaxPlace=2;
        MinPlace=1;
    }

    if(ThirdKeyIn>Bigger){
        Bigger=ThirdKeyIn;//save ThirdKeyIn value into Bigger
        MaxPlace=3;
    }
    if(ThirdKeyIn<Smaller){
        Smaller=ThirdKeyIn;//save ThirdKeyIn value into Smaller
        MinPlace=3;
    }


    printf("Bigger value is :%d \n",Bigger);
    printf("Bigger Place is :%d \n",MaxPlace);
    printf("Smaller value is :%d \n",Smaller);
    printf("Smaller Place is :%d \n",MinPlace);
    return 0;
}
```

### 5.

try by youself

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple points that you need to take care of.

If you need to run your program multiple times then you need to a sentinel controlled loop (e.g. controlled by a condition such as yes/no or specific number of repetitions), not an infinite loop i.e. `while(1)`. If not, the `while` loop is unnecessary.

At the end of the program, `getchar()` blocks until <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is pressed so you don't need that `while(1)` there.

You can simply use a block for writing multiple statements in your `if-else-if` so you don't have to check for the index again at the end e.g.:

```
if ((x1 > x2) && (x1 > x3) && (x1 > x4))
{ 
    xlarge = x1; // assign the number to xlarge, not x1 = xlarge
    ixlarge = 1; // assign the position of the number here!!!
}
```

You're assigning `x1 = xlarge;` which is incorrect as `x1` already contains a value input by the user. This value will be overwritten by a garbage value stored in `xlarge` because it has not been initialized. It should be: `xlarge = x1;`.

In an `if-else`, you don't need to check the last condition i.e. three alternatives have been tested so you can simply write the last result without testing it in the `else`.

```
     if ( condition-1 ) /* do something */
else if ( condition-2 ) /* do something */
else if ( condition-3 ) /* do something */
else                    /* do something if all other conditions are false */
```

Always initialize your variables so that you know for sure that they are in a known state and won't cause a *used-before-initialization* causing [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Here's an example ([live](http://ideone.com/3nxABI)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 0, x4 = 0;
    int xlarge = 0, xsmall = 0, ixlarge = 0, ixsmall = 0;

    printf("Enter x1, x2, x3, x4: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &x1, &x2, &x3, &x4);

    if ((x1 > x2) && (x1 > x3) && (x1 > x4))
    { 
        xlarge = x1;
        ixlarge = 1;
    }
    else if ((x2 > x1) && (x2 > x3) && (x2 > x4))
    { 
        xlarge = x2;
        ixlarge = 2;
    }
    else if ((x3 > x1) && (x3 > x2) && (x3 > x4))
    { 
        xlarge = x3;
        ixlarge = 3;
    }
    else if ((x4 > x1) && (x4 > x2) && (x4 > x3))
    { 
        xlarge = x4;
        ixlarge = 4;
    }

    if ((x1 < x2) && (x1 < x3) && (x1 < x4))
    {
        xsmall = x1;
        ixsmall = 1;
    }
    else if ((x2 < x1) && (x2 < x3) && (x2 < x4))
    {
        xsmall = x2;
        ixsmall = 2;
    }
    else if ((x3 < x1) && (x3 < x2) && (x3 < x4))
    {
        xsmall = x3;
        ixsmall = 3;
    }
    else if ((x4 < x1) && (x4 < x2) && (x4 < x3))
    {
        xsmall = x4;
        ixsmall = 4;
    }

    printf("Largest  %d @ [index: %d]\n", xlarge, ixlarge);
    printf("Smallest %d @ [index: %d]\n", xsmall, ixsmall);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter x1, x2, x3, x4: 1 2 3 4
Largest  4 @ [index: 4]
Smallest 1 @ [index: 1]
```

---

If you're allowed to use macros then you can write for your conditions:

```
#define IS_GREATER(n,x,y,z)     ((n > x) && (n > y) && (n > z))
#define IS_SMALLER(n,x,y,z)     ((n < x) && (n < y) && (n < z))
```

Here's an example with macros: http://ideone.com/G18hci

---

**NOTE**: Please do keep in mind that your solution doesn't take care of duplicate elements use case or the case where all the elements are the same.